# Json data Parse in node.js handlebars

Tags: json, node.js

Form API I have JSON data as below.I am new in node.js so I don't know how to parse JSON data.

```
[
  {
   "Detail": " Rs. 1001 Full Talktime Topup Rs.1001 Full Talktime",
   "Amount": "1001",
   "Validity": "Unlimited"
  },
  {
   "Detail": " Rs. 1000 Full Talktime Topup Rs.1050  more than Full Talktime",
   "Amount": "1000",
   "Validity": "Unlimited"
  },
  {
   "Detail": " Rs. 899 Full Talktime Topup Rs.899 Full Talktime",
   "Amount": "899",
   "Validity": "Unlimited"
  },
  {
   "Detail": " Rs. 501 Full Talktime Topup Rs.501 Full Talktime",
   "Amount": "501",
   "Validity": "Unlimited"
  },
  {
   "Detail": " Rs. 500 Full Talktime Topup Rs.500 Full Talktime",
   "Amount": "500",
   "Validity": "Unlimited"
  },
  {
   "Detail": " Rs. 225 Full Talktime Topup Rs.225 Full Talktime",
   "Amount": "225",
   "Validity": "30 days"
  },
  {
   "Detail": " Rs. 59 Full Talktime Topup Rs.59 Full Talktime",
   "Amount": "59",
   "Validity": "7 days"
  },
  {
   "Detail": " Rs. 32 Full Talktime Topup Rs.32 Full Talktime",
   "Amount": "32",
   "Validity": "3 days"
  }
]
```

handlebars.registerHelper is

```
hbs.registerHelper("FTT", function(author){
   return JSON.stringify(code);
});
```

and in  Handlebars template

```
{{#each FTT}}
     <tr>
         <td>Hello</td>
         <td>{{FTT.[0].Detail}}</td>
         <td>{{this.[0].Amount}}</td>
         <td>{{Validity}}</td>
     </tr>
{{/each}}
```

In FTT not displaing anything. I also try dissfrent sugeestion but still not getting anywhere.
Any sugession ,

Comment: use `JSON.parse(code)`, `JSON.stringify(code)` converts it to a string.

Comment: I also try that but each is not looping throw FTT can you suggest any live example for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example I hope this helps:

```js
$(function() {
  var context = {};

  Handlebars.registerHelper('ftt', function(author) {
    Object.assign(context, {
      FTT: jsonData
    });
  });

  var theTemplateScript = $("#ftt-html").html();
  var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
  var theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(context);

  $('.content-placeholder').html(theCompiledHtml);

});


var jsonData = [{
    "Detail": " Rs. 1001 Full Talktime Topup Rs.1001 Full Talktime",
    "Amount": "1001",
    "Validity": "Unlimited"
  },
  {
    "Detail": " Rs. 1000 Full Talktime Topup Rs.1050  more than Full Talktime",
    "Amount": "1000",
    "Validity": "Unlimited"
  },
  {
    "Detail": " Rs. 899 Full Talktime Topup Rs.899 Full Talktime",
    "Amount": "899",
    "Validity": "Unlimited"
  },
  {
    "Detail": " Rs. 501 Full Talktime Topup Rs.501 Full Talktime",
    "Amount": "501",
    "Validity": "Unlimited"
  },
  {
    "Detail": " Rs. 500 Full Talktime Topup Rs.500 Full Talktime",
    "Amount": "500",
    "Validity": "Unlimited"
  },
  {
    "Detail": " Rs. 225 Full Talktime Topup Rs.225 Full Talktime",
    "Amount": "225",
    "Validity": "30 days"
  },
  {
    "Detail": " Rs. 59 Full Talktime Topup Rs.59 Full Talktime",
    "Amount": "59",
    "Validity": "7 days"
  },
  {
    "Detail": " Rs. 32 Full Talktime Topup Rs.32 Full Talktime",
    "Amount": "32",
    "Validity": "3 days"
  }
];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="ftt-html" type="text/x-ftt-template">
  
  {{ftt}}

  {{#each FTT}}
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>{{Detail}}</td>
    <td>{{Amount}}</td>
    <td>{{Validity}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}

</script>

<div class="content-placeholder"></div>
```